# resource file is not found when using iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the following code.  word.txt is in "Supporting Files":

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"words.txt"]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

When I run using the simulator, data is not read properly but if I use the actual device, it works fine.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it and it seems to work for me:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if (data) {
        NSLog(@"DATA:%@",data);
    }
```

And to set it to a string:

```
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"WORDS:%@",string);
```